# Two-way frequency table row and column labels

Tags: r, frequency

I want to style the output of `table()`. Suppose I have the following:

```
dat$a <- c(1,2,3,4,4,3,4,2,2,2)
dat$b <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,4,3,2,2)
table(dat$a,dat$b)

    1   2   3   4
1  50   0   0   0
2   0 150  50   0
3   0  50  50   0
4  50   0   0 100
```

There are two problems with this. First, it doesn't give me the correct frequencies. Additionally, it has no row or column labels. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009934/transformin-a-two-way-table-into-pairwise-list-of-counts-in-r), and the table works for both frequency counts and axis labels. Is there an issue because this way subsets from a data frame? I would appreciate any tips on both fixing the frequency counts and adding style to the table.

Comment: How many `nrow(dat)` do you have?

Comment: The margins are labeled if you use `with(dat,table(a,b))` or `table(a=dat$a,b=dat$b)` or `table(dat[,c("a","b")])`. I don't know why your frequencies are off. For the example you give, the frequencies should be only 1/50th of the counts you're showing.

Comment: `dat` is likely a 500 row data frame, which has been filled via recycling.

Comment: I did have 500 rows, and I ran it in my program and it gave me the correct frequencies (so that's not an issue anymore). I tried doing `table(dat[,c("a","b")])` but still didn't get any labels. If it makes a difference, I'm running this in shiny using renderTable.

Comment: I reformatted my question and posted it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575571/r-shiny-dnn-in-table-not-appearing-in-rendertable).

Answer (score 4):

The only problem is the way that you are inputting arguments to `table`. To get the desired output (with labels), use the data frame as argument, not 2 vectors (the columns). If you have a larger data frame, use only the subset that you want.

```
 a <- c(1,2,3,4,4,3,4,2,2,2)
 b <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,4,3,2,2)
 dat <- data.frame(a,b)
 table(dat)
```

Gives me the output:

```
   b
a   1 2 3 4
  1 1 0 0 0
  2 0 3 1 0
  3 0 1 1 0
  4 1 0 0 2
```

It shouldn't give the wrong frequencies, even with your approach. You could try restarting your R session to check this.

Comment: When I tried, I did `a <- dat$a` and `b <- dat$b` and then `table(a,b)` and it gave me the correct frequencies but still no labels. Is this what you meant?

Comment: That still just gives me the table with no labels. Is there anyway to manually add them? If it makes a difference, I'm using renderTable in Shiny.

Comment: @KiraTebbe Yes, it makes difference to use `renderTable` in Shiny. I suggest that you open another question with a more detailed code, maybe posting your `ui.R` and `server.R` code, or part of it. We can not reproduce your problem if we do not have the same conditions.

Comment: I reformatted my question and posted it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575571/r-shiny-dnn-in-table-not-appearing-in-rendertable)