# R Shiny: dnn in table not appearing in renderTable()

Tags: r, shiny

I have a table made with `renderTable()` and I want to label the rows and columns (not each one, just overall). When I run the code in the console, the labels appear. But when I run the code in the active Shiny environment with `renderTable()`, the table appears without the labels. Here's my (summarized) code:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  sidebarPanel(),
  mainPanel(
     tabPanel("Pairwise Table", tableOutput("pairs") )
))

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
   output$pairs <- renderTable({
      dat <- data.frame(hiv=c(0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1), 
                       age=c(50,55,50,60,40,45,40,55,50,60))
      tab <- table(dat$hiv, dat$age, dnn=c("hiv","age"))
      tab
   })
 })
```

When I run the code within output$pairs in the console, it produces the table with the labels (which is what I want):

```
   age
hiv 40 45 50 55 60
  0  1  0  2  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

When I run in through Shiny, it plots the same table, just without any labels. Any idea as to why?

Comment: Adding
caption = "hiv-age",
  caption.placement = getOption("xtable.caption.placement", "top"), 
  caption.width = getOption("xtable.caption.width", NULL)
as options to renderTable (between } and )) allows you to print text above the table, but it is not yet quite wat you want I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Shiny doesn't support this kind of display of tables. I developed a work around, hope it is useful.

Instead of using `table`, use `ftable`, and wrap it in a `data.frame`. Here is how your `shinyServer` should be:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$pairs <- renderTable({
    dat <- data.frame(hiv=c(0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1), 
                      age=c(50,55,50,60,40,45,40,55,50,60))
    tab <- data.frame(format(ftable(dat), 
                             method = "compact", quote = F))
    tab
  }, include.rownames=FALSE, include.colnames = FALSE)
})
```

Comment: That works if `dat` has just two variables, but what if it has many more and I  want to subset just two? Using `$` doesn't seem to label it (just has a blank ` | ` as a label). Any tips?

Comment: You could use common subsetting, so that your code would be: `tab <-data.frame(format(ftable(dat[, c(1,2)]), method = "compact", quote = F))
`. Change the numbers by the correspondent column numbers in your data frame.